# How to rotate model .obj around its center when i use THREE.OBJLoader

Tags: rotation, three.js

I use THREE.OBJLoader for import model obj I use code from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html#L75 
But I have problem when i need to rotate model that not rotate around itscenter. if i need it rotate around its center. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry );
```

This will translate the geometry so that it's bounding box is centered at the origin in the object's local coordinate system. Now, when you rotate it, it will rotate around it's "center".

Comment: The latest version of three.js produces the following warning: THREE.GeometryUtils: .center() has been moved to Geometry. Use geometry.center() instead.